# What does sb. mean in NED?

Tags: abbreviations

What does '***sb.***' mean in this dictionary, [NED](https://archive.org/stream/oed9barch#page/n465/mode/1up), below?

[image]

Comment: See page 12, sb. = substantive. Basically, it's noun.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I can see them on [page xxvi](https://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/n23/mode/1up).

Comment: I think you're right! The Volume IX, Part II (SU-TH) on Archive.org doesn't have the page number for *List of Abbreviations, Signs, &c.* (I guess that it's page vii), so I had to use the page number according to the slider bar given by Archive.org. You'd found another volume. This is fascinating! (I think I'm going to download them!)

Comment: I've not found it myself. It's introduced on [ELL](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/735/resources-for-learning-english/739#739), and I knew it from Mister StoneyB, who if necessary quotes some words from the dictionary, now and then.

Comment: I think the list of abbreviations can be found at the beginning of every volume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 12 (*List of Abbreviations, Signs, &c.*), *sb.* is defined as "substantive".

This term is used for "noun" in older works on language, including older grammars and dictionaries. In the current version of the Oxford English Dictionary, they went and replaced all their *sb.*'s with *n.*'s.

You can find more information in [this section on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun#Substantive_as_a_word_for_noun),

> **Substantive as a word for noun**
>   *"Substantive" redirects here. For other uses, see [Substance (disambiguation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substance_(disambiguation)).*
>
> Starting with old Latin grammars, many European languages use some form of the word substantive as the basic term for noun (for example, Spanish *sustantivo*, "noun"). Nouns in the dictionaries of such languages are demarked by the abbreviation s. or sb. instead of n, which may be used for proper nouns instead. This corresponds to those grammars in which nouns and adjectives phase into each other in more areas than, for example, the English term predicate adjective entails. In French and Spanish, for example, adjectives frequently act as nouns referring to people who have the characteristics of the adjective. The most common metalanguage to name this concept is *nominalization*. [...]

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought that ‘talented’ must have been derived from its verb, as ‘gifted’ is from [<gift v + -ed>](https://archive.org/stream/oed04arch#page/157/mode/1up). But not it is, they say.

Comment: @Listenever Compare *legged* in "a four-legged animal".  This is the same *-ed*.